# Formal proof of implication

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I am currently stuck on this particular task. I need to formally prove that

```
(∃a ∀b (b<a)) → (∀a ∃b (a<b))
```

Now, what I have so far is that I need to prove that the above implication is a tautology, and that my premises are `(∃a ∀b (b<a))` A and `(∀a ∃b (a<b))` B.

I am not sure where to go next...

I tried assuming that A is True.
Next I assume that A→B is True.
Using Modus Ponens if A and A→B are True I can prove B.
Therefore, if A and B are True the implication of both must be True.
But I am not convinced this works.

Alternatively I tried assuming A is true.
If A is true it means `∃a ∃b (b<a)` is also true.
That means there must be a `b` that satisfies the same condition? If `a` and `b`are swapped? So `∃a ∃b (a<b)`? and then somehow deduce `∀a ∃b (a<b)`?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It is not prop calculus but predicate logic.

Comment: Bit $<$ means "less than"  between numbers ?

Comment: "`I tried assuming that A is True. Next I assume that A→B is True.`" That is where you went awry.  Never assume the thing that you want to prove.  You should assume $A$ then *derive* $B$ under that assumption, so that you may deduce that $A\to B$ holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried assuming that A is True. Next I assume that A→B is True.

That is clearly awry. Never assume the thing that you want to prove. You should assume 
$A$ then derive $B$ under that assumption, so that you may deduce that $A→B$ holds.

> Alternatively I tried assuming A is true. If A is true it means $∃a ∃b (b<a)$ is also true. That means there must be a b that satisfies the same condition? If a and b are swapped? So $∃a ∃b (a<b)$? and then somehow deduce $∀a ∃b (a<b)$?

Not quite.  You don't derive an existance from an universal.

But the technique you need is alpha-replacement.   We can safely substitute the bound term with any token that does not already occur within the scope of the quantifier.   So think of it as proving $\exists a~\forall b~(b<a)\to \forall b~\exists a~(b<a)$ then juggling the letters.

- Begin

  - Assume $\exists a~\forall b~(b<a)$

    - Let $y$ be an arbirary term.

      - Let $x$ be a witness for the assumption.
      - $\forall b~(b<x)$ via instantiation of existential bound $a$ to witness $x$.
      - $y<x$ via instantiation of universal bound $b$ to arbitrary $y$.
    - $\exists b~(y<b)$ via generalisation of witness $x$ to existential bound $b$.
  - $\forall a~\exists b~(a<b)$ via generalisation of arbitrary $y$ to universal bound $a$
- Done: $\exists a~\forall b~(b<a)\to \forall a~\exists b~(a<b)$

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are stating this for real numbers (that is to say, you omit to write "$\in \Bbb R$" in the quantifiers). Suppose that A is true, so that there exists a number $a$ such that for every number $b$ the relation $b<a$ holds; if $c$ is any number, then $c<a$ hence B holds. So, A implies B as desired.

Comment: Or else, let know what "<" signifies.

Comment: It doesn't matter what relation $<$ signifies

Comment: Indeed: $\exists a~\forall b~R(b,a)~~\to~~\forall a~\exists b~R(a,b)$ for any binary relation $R$

Answer (score 0):

When you have to prove that some sentence of the form "$(\forall x\in X)\,P(x)$, you should start by : "Let $x$ be some element of $X$, let's prove $P(x)$".

Here, suppose "$(\exists a_0)(\forall b)\, b<a_0$" is true. Let's prove "$(\forall b) (\exists a)\, b<a$" (I changed the letters, to simplify the proof).

So let $b$ be some element. The $a_0$ given by the hypothesis is now a good candidate for the conclusion : let $a=a_0$, we have $b<a$, so that the conclusion is true.

What you have to understand is that in "$(\exists a)(\forall b)\, P(a,b)$", the "$a$" is *the same* for every $b$. In "$(\forall b) (\exists a)\, P(a,b)$", $a$ is dependent on $b$ : you can chose it *after* $b$ has been given.

One final note : your "$<$" relation is quite odd : of all the $b$ that must verify $b<a$, there is in particular $a$, so $a$ should verify $a<a$. Maybe a bad notation ? At least a confusing one :-)

Comment: To be even more precise : $\left[(\exists a)(\forall b)P(a,b)\right]\Longrightarrow \left[(\forall b)(\exists a)P(a,b)\right]$ is a tautology for alla predicates $P(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you, helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $$\tag1\exists a\forall b(b<a).$$ 
Accordingly, let $a_0$ such that $$\tag2\forall b(b<a_0).$$ 
We want to show (based on the hypothesis $(1)$) that $\forall a\exists b(a<b)$. So let $a$ be arbitrary. By specialization from $(2)$, we have $a<a_0$. So by letting $b=a_0$, we have $a<b$, i.e., $\exists b(a<b)$. As $a$ was arbitrary, we showed $$ \forall a\exists b(a<b).$$
As all this happend under the hypothesis $(1)$, we have
$$\exists a\forall b(b<a)\to\forall a\exists b(a<b). $$

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now!